# Does firebase push method with empty values, just for getting the ID, trigger the child_added event?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Reading firebase real time database docs it is not clear when the `child_added` event triggers exactly. It says it triggers when a new child is added to a node, so far so good. The docs also say that, if you want to get the next available unique Id on a path, you just call `push()` on that path to get a reference that will have a unique ID. However, it is not clear if this empty push call will be considered an event of `child_added` or if it will be ignored. Once you get the ID, you can not push again or you will get another ID (that is just my guess) so you just set the given reference with the data you want it to contain. It is not clear either if this last operation will trigger a child_added event.

Let me ilustrate with a bit of code with inline questions:

```js
const dbRef = db.child('todos')
const newTodoRef = dbRef.push() // does this trigger child_added event?
newTodoRef.set({ id: newTodoRef.key, name: 'test' }) // and does this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `push()` without any arguments does not write any data, so it does not trigger any events yet. It merely creates a reference in the code to a new unique location.

Calling `set(...)` on this reference *does* then write data, so does trigger events.